# How to wrap computation graph into layer in Keras?

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, keras

Previously I was writing my own blocks of layers as functions, like this:

```
def vgg_stack(...):
    def inner(x):

        x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
        x = layers.Conv2D(...)(x)
        x = layers.Conv2D(...)(x)

        x = layers.MaxPool2D(pool_size=(2,2)(x)
        x = layers.Dropout(0.25)(x)
        ...

        return x
    return inner
```

From such functions I was able to construct graphs in consistent way, like

```
x1 = layers.Input(...)
x2 = layers.Input(...)

x1 = vgg_stack(...)(x1)
x2 = vgg_stack(...)(x2)

x = layers.concatenate([x1, x2])

x = final_MLP(...)(x)
```

and so on, combining keras layers and my own functions in the same way.

Unfortunately, this approach stuck on layers wrappers [like `TimeDistributed`](https://keras.io/layers/wrappers/#timedistributed): this constructor accepts only layers, not functions. If I pass my function to it, it complains

```
AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'built'
```

So, I need to [implement custom `Layer`](https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/). But suppose I already have my functions like above written. What is the simplest was to wrap such function into a `Layer`?